# var hoisting and value between redeclaration

Tags: javascript

Run below code in Node environment. Running it in browser console doesn't allow to redeclare variable of var.

```
console.log(a);
var a = 5;
```

According to hoisting, the above code is going to look like this

```
var a = undefined;
console.log(a); // undefined
a = 5;
```

`a` variable is being hoisted to the top of the file. JS Engine allocates memory for this variable before the execution. The question is why below code consols `5` instead of undefined.

```
var a = 5;
console.log(a);
var a = 6;
```

I'm looking at this code and imagining that it's going to look like this:

```
var a = 5;
var a = undefined;
console.log(a); // undefined
a = 6;
```

I'd like to be sure of the answer instead of guessing. The JS Engine is smart enough to see that `a` variable is already declared and is going to ignore the next var expression and rehoisting in such case? So the output should be looking like:

```
var a = 5;
console.log(a); // 5
a = 6;
```

So it's like:

1. JS Engine sees for the first time declaration (in this case along with initialization) of `a` variable so it's allocating memory.
2. JS Engine sees for the second time declaration of `a` variable but is going to ignore the hoisting because variable of given name is already in the memory.

Am I wrong in something?

Comment: You can't redeclare a variable in JS, as you said, multiple `var`s are ignored.

Comment: All the `var a` are hoisted *once*. Also, hoisting is not actually "re-writing" the code. Moreover, hoisting doesn't mean it assigns an `undefined`, it's just the default value. So, `console.log(a); var a = 5;` is `var a; console.log(a); a = 5;`

Comment: Why can't I find a good dupetarget for this?! It **has** to be my search-fu letting me down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**: In modern JavaScript, `var` should never be used. Use `let` or `const`.

---

The JavaScript engine handles `var` in two steps:

1. Upon entering the global scope or a function scope, it processes every `var` in the entire scope, defining variables for the them initialized wit the value `undefined`. If a variable is declared more than once with `var`, it's **exactly** as though it were declared once.
2. Then it starts the step-by-step execution of the code. In that step-by-step execution, any initializer on a `var` statement (the `= 5` in `var a = 5`) is considered an assignment. So `var a = 5` is treated exactly like `a = 5` at this point.

So in your example:

```
var a = 5;
var a = undefined;
console.log(a); // undefined
a = 6;
```

It's **as though** you had written this:

```
var a = 5;
a = undefined;
console.log(a); // undefined
a = 6;
```

or this:

```
a = 5;
var a = undefined;
console.log(a); // undefined
a = 6;
```

or this:

```
a = 5;
a = undefined;
console.log(a); // undefined
var a = 6;
```

or this:

```
var a;
a = 5;
a = undefined;
console.log(a); // undefined
a = 6;
```

or this:

```
a = 5;
a = undefined;
console.log(a); // undefined
a = 6;
var a;
```

or even this (but please don't! :-) ):

```
var a = 5;
var a = undefined;
console.log(a); // undefined
var a = 6;
var a;
```

That is, first all the variables declared with `var` are created (and only once), then the code runs as though any initializers on them were assignments.

---

This is not how `let`, `const`, and `class` declarations are handled (collectively: lexically-scoped declarations). First: Multiple declarations in the same scope are an error (including if one of them is with `var` and the other is with one of the lexically-scoped ones). Second: They're hoisted (in Step 1 above), but the hoisted binding¹ is *uninitialized* until the declaration is executed in the step-by-step code, at which point it's initialized (either with the value from the initializer, or with `undefined` if it's just e.g. `let a;`). The time between entry to the scope and the point the binding is initialized is called the Temporal Dead Zone. `var` doesn't have it because `var` variables are initialized when they're created (with the value `undefined`), but `let`, `const`, and `class` declarations do.

---

¹ The term *binding* is the general term for variable-like things. In the code:

```
function example(p) {
    var v;
    let l;
    const c = 42;
    function f() {
    }
    class C {}
}
```

the *bindings* created upon entering the `example` function's scope are `p` (a parameter), `v` (a `var` variable), `l` (a `let` variable), `c` (a `const` constant), `f` (the binding created by a function *declaration*), and `C` (the binding created by a `class` *declaration*). (Note: function and `class` *expressions* are handled slightly differently.)